# Hide everything except for one folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to hide everything unless it is in my `Scripts` folder, is there a way to do this?

I tried to do this, but it doesn't work, it just hides everything.

```
{
    "files.exclude":
    {
        "**/*": true,
        "**/Scripts": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exclusion setting currently does not allow to build rules like that. I suggest you open an issue on our bug tracker at GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thanks!